# How to assign a grid of point data to corresponding grid of polygons

Tags: qgis, polygon, point

I'm using QGIS 2/12.3

I have a point layer with modelled data on a 1km grid, each point has a value (0-5, modelling temperatures) and lies at the centre point of a 1km grid square.

I also have a polygon layer which is of 1km squares.

I need to assign the points values to the corresponding polygons.

If I use intersect, the output layer is points, not polygons.

(I need to do this so I can intersect the km squares with another layer to find the average value for each polygon).

I realise one way might be to add a new column to the attribute table and paste data across - but I need some guidance.

Comment: Try completing a [Spatial Join](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_spatial_joins.html)

Comment: You may need to do a spatial join that joins the ids from the polygons to the points then do a database join to link the info back to the polygons using the Ids - hope this makes sense.

Comment: Not entirely - I assume data management -> join attributes, but how to I join databases?

Answer (score 1):

This is just a visual explanation of `Join attributes by location`.

(1) Let's assume you have a point layer (*Point_temperature*) with `id` and `mod_temp` fields.

(2) You also have a polygon layer (*Grid*) which has its own `id` field. (*Note this `id` is unrelated with another `id` in the point layer.*)

[image]

(3) Go to `Vector | Data management | Join attributes by location`.

(4) Make sure the **Target** is your Grid layer, and select `Take attributes of the first located feature` option.

(5) It will return a `Joined layer` (new polygon layer) in which you will see `id_1` and `mod_temp` copied from the point layer.

[image]